# How to create conditional import using sass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

I'm implementing the translation concept in a [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) website (Engish, Arabic).

I'm changing the html tag *"dir"* attribute to *"rlt"* in order to change the website direction. But that doesn't affect the boostrap directions (margins, spacing and other ...). So I'm using the [bootstrap rtl version](https://github.com/MahdiMajidzadeh/bootstrap-v4-rtl) to handle the last. Right now, I'm switching between the two bootstrap version using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/).

```
${{#index.isEnglish}}$
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.css">
${{/index.isEnglish}}$
${{^index.isEnglish}}$
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.ar.css">
${{/index.isEnglish}}$
```

The code above the is working well!

Now, what if I need to create my own theme by overriding the boostrap colors and other?

> [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) one of the best practices to override the bootstrap using the sass extending concept.

If I gonna apply the mentioned concept I will be in a problem.

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-v4-rtl/scss/bootstrap-rtl";
```

So my question is how to create conditional @import using sass depending on the website language? (html direction).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle this using Sass, you could proceed as follow:

```sass
html[dir='rtl'] {
  @import "node_modules/bootstrap-v4-rtl/scss/bootstrap-rtl";
}

html[dir='ltr'] {
  @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
}
```

This method works but will generate an **html pre-selector** for each of your rules, which will have an impact on the weight of the file.